# How do you automate the testing of CAPTCHA using WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I tried this but I can't bypass the CAPTCHA

// clicked on captcha

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,25);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(
            By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
            By.xpath("//div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-border']"))).click();
```

Comment: The whole point of a captcha is that you cannot automate around or bypass it.  If this is your system, make the captcha only appear in production, while you automate against the dev environments.  If this is not your system, then the site owners have added the captcha precisely to stop you from doing this.